# How to mange names in output text file in R?

Tags: r, text

data:

```
    sam:
     res = 0.25 , res1=0.30
    bad: 
     res= 0.30 , res1=0.23
```

code:

```
    write.table(sam, file = "C:\\Users\\data1.txt", append = F, sep = " ", row.names = TRUE,col.names = TRUE)
   write.table(bad, file = "C:\\Users\\data1.txt", append = T, sep = " ",row.names = TRUE, col.names = TRUE)
```

output of `data1`:

```
   "x"
   "1" 0.25
    "x"
   "1" 0.3
```

In fact, I want the output in the text file `data1` to be something like this:

```
              res      res1
 sam           0.25    0.30
 bad           0.3     0.23
```

Any idea is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can supply a named vector in `write.table()`.  You'll just need to set the second set of column names to `FALSE` since they've already been provided in the first initial call.

```
sam <- 0.25; bad <- 0.30

write.table(c(sam = sam), col.names = "res", file = "data")
write.table(c(bad = bad), col.names = FALSE, file = "data", append = TRUE)

## read it back in
read.table("data")
#      res
# sam 0.25
# bad 0.30
```

In response to your comment, you can write a helper function to do the appending once the file is initialized.  Then we can read it as a list so we have a choice between returning a data frame or a matrix.

```
sam <- 0.25
bad = 0.3

## initial file creation
write.table(cbind(sam, bad), "data", row.names = FALSE)

## function to append to 'data'
wtFun <- function(x) {
    write.table(x, "data", append = TRUE, col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
}

## new values
sam2 <- 0.99
bad2 <- 25

## append new values
wtFun(cbind(sam2, bad2))

## read the file as a list and set the names
res <- setNames(
    scan("data", what = list(0, 0), skip = 1L),
    scan("data", what = "", nlines = 1L)
)

## 'res' as a matrix
do.call(rbind, res)
#     [,1]  [,2]
# sam 0.25  0.99
# bad 0.30 25.00

## 'res' as a data frame
as.data.frame(res)
#    sam  bad
# 1 0.25  0.3
# 2 0.99 25.0
```

Comment: Thanks,How to add a scond column `res2` with two new values correspond to `sam and bad`

Comment: @Barry - I added some things.  Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks what you have done is great. but the new values should have a different column name so `res and res1`.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. But you might be better off just naming the columns after you read the file.  Otherwise it's probably going to get tricky.

Answer (score 1):

This will work better if you write `sam` and `bad` as `data.frame`s (or matrices), instead of atomics. For example,

```
sam <- 0.25
bad <- 0.30
##
write.table(
  data.frame(res=sam,row.names="sam"),
  file="F:/temp/data1.txt",
  append=F,sep=" ",
  col.names=TRUE,
  row.names=TRUE)
##
write.table(
  data.frame(res=bad,row.names="bad"),
  file="F:/temp/data1.txt",
  append=T,sep=" ",
  col.names=FALSE,
  row.names=TRUE)
##
R> read.table("F:/temp/data1.txt",header=TRUE)
     res
sam 0.25
bad 0.30
```

---

IMO though, it's not a good idea to force the `row.names` attribute like this because if you append an object to the file with a row name that already exists, you will get an error when you try to read it back in since the `row.names` attribute cannot contain duplicate values. You would be better off doing something like

```
write.table(
  data.frame(name="sam",res=sam),
  file="F:/temp/data1.txt",
  append=F,sep=" ",
  col.names=TRUE,
  row.names=FALSE)
##
write.table(
  data.frame(name="bad",res=bad),
  file="F:/temp/data1.txt",
  append=T,sep=" ",
  col.names=FALSE,
  row.names=FALSE)
##
R> read.table("F:/temp/data1.txt",header=TRUE)
  name  res
1  sam 0.25
2  bad 0.30
```